# Script that replaces strings doesn't work on some sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've created a simple Chrome extension that seeks for certain strings using regex and replaces matches with predefined text. It works well on most websites, but somehow the script doesn't take effect on, for example, Lifehacker (like this page http://lifehacker.com/5939740/five-best-audio-editing-applications?popular=true ). 
The code is:

```
$('p, h1, h2, h3, span, .content, .post-body').each(function(){
        //do something with $(this)
});
```

Any ideas why is Lifehacker's site resistant to my script?

Comment: Already looked at the possibility of AJAX / frames?

Comment: Are you bundling jQuery with your Chrome Extension?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is bundled with the extension.

Comment: @RobW, what do you mean?

Comment: @groovy354 When the elements are dynamicly generated, you cannot select them on start. And, when the page is contained within a frame, you cannot select them, unless you use `all_frames:true`, or `$('iframe').contents().find(....)`.

Comment: @RobW, how can I affect dynamically loaded content in the instant it's loaded?

Comment: Polling or DOM mutation events/observers. The best/easiest approach depends on your use case.

Answer (score 4):

Change your script to something like this:

```
(function($){
  $('p, h1, h2, h3, span, .content, .post-body').each(function(){
     console.log($(this));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

On their website `$` is not used as an alias for a jQuery object. The code above acts like a self-executing anonymous functions that will take their jQuery object as a parameter and treat it as `$`. Alternatevely you can replace all `$`'s in your code to `jQuery`.

**UPD**: Also in your extension I would check first if `jQuery` object exists/loaded on the page and use `jQuery` instead of `$`, since `$` may be used by other JavaScript libraries (like mootools).

Comment: what does the error say? Is jQuery loaded? Can you post your code? Simple `it doesn't work` doesn't describe your problem.

Comment: It doesn't return any errors, but the text is left unchanged. "(function($){
 jQuery("document").ready(function(){
  jQuery('p, h1, h2, h3, span, .content, .post-body').each(function(){
   parse(this);
  });
 });
})(jQuery);"
The parse() function replaces any matches for a regex with a predefined string.

Comment: replace `parse(this);` to `console.log($(this));` and tell me what you see in developer's console.

Comment: I used console.log($(this)); and realized it was the parse function that was buggy. Question dismissed. Thank you all for your help!